# How reliable is the list of HCN-numbers considering this link?

Tags: number-theory, prime-factorization, divisor-counting-function

Here

http://wwwhomes.uni-bielefeld.de/achim/highly.html

there is a quite shocking link that states that a false algorithm was published and even a number theoretic expert failed to detect that.

In view of this , how reliable is the external link of the $10,000$ first highly composite numbers here

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Highly_composite_number

and the subsequent external link even containing over $700,000$ HCN. It is also claimed that the calculation is extremely fast.

I asked a question about an efficient algorithm for checking whether a number is highly composite and the answer was that it is very difficult to check this.

But if the used algorithm actually guarantees to find the first over $700,000$ HCN-numbers, the algorithm used should be very efficient considering the calculation times.

> Can anyone explain the main idea of the algorithm used in the calculation of the huge list of highly composite numbers ? In particaular, how can I prove the given estimation for the exponents due to Ramanujan ?

I also invite everyone to comment on the "joke" that was apparantly made.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

make an answer. Most anything you might want will be among the [publications of Jean-Louis Nicolas](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/publications.html)

He published a summary in English called [On Highly Composite Numbers](http://math.univ-lyon1.fr/~nicolas/hcnrevisited.pdf) which is currently number 80 on his publication page. His student, Guy Robin, is the one who constructed an algorithm for finding all HC numbers between consecutive SHC numbers. I believe Robin later wrote up that algorithm, which was originally in his dissertation.

I don't know what algorithms might be involved in your links. I should emphasize that, done correctly and carefully, finding the SHC numbers is fast enough; given that you have found one, the next one is what you have multiplied by a single prime.   If I had to find all HC numbers up to a large bound and it needed to be correct, I would get someone to translate Robin's note for me. I already know how to find the SHC numbers up to some bound, and have done so.

[image]

[image]